# What is the difference between the PHP header and the HTML meta tag?

Tags: php, html

What is the difference between the PHP header and the HTML meta tag?

More precisely, I have a HTML page that is parsed in PHP and then send to the browser with an echo instruction.

I have a different behavior if before the echo instruction I send a

`header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8)`

or, without sendig the header, I include in the HTML page the

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>`

Comment: Sorry, I have used some HTML tags that are not visible in my question. I want to know the difference between the header instruction in PHP and the "head" tag in HTML. I have a different behaviour if I send the header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8") in PHP and the echo the HTML page, or including the "meta" tag in HTMl with the "content-type".

Comment: This question has already been answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937163/difference-meta-and-php-header

Comment: Please make some research before asking questions, if you had just googled "What is the difference between the PHP header and the HTML meta tag?" which is your question, you would have find the solution alone ;)